# How to write a migration changing id to uuid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```
class ChangeIdtoUuiDforcarts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    rename_column :carts, :id, :uuid
    change_column :carts, :uuid, 'using uuid::uuid'
  end
end
```

I have tried the above migration, but it gives the following syntax error

```
-- rename_column(:carts, :id, :uuid)
   -> 0.0032s
-- change_column(:carts, :uuid, "using uuid::uuid")
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "using"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "carts" ALTER COLUMN "uuid" TYPE using uuid::uui...
                                                     ^
: ALTER TABLE "carts" ALTER COLUMN "uuid" TYPE using uuid::uuid
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:90:in `exec'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:90:in `async_exec'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-

4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:437:in `change_column'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/home/gvpmahesh/code/shij/core/db/migrate/20160812081429_change_idto_uui_dforcarts.rb:4:in `change'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `exec_migration'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "using"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "carts" ALTER COLUMN "uuid" TYPE using uuid::uui...
                                                     ^
: ALTER TABLE "carts" ALTER COLUMN "uuid" TYPE using uuid::uuid
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:90:in `exec'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:90:in `async_exec'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:437:in `change_column'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/home/gvpmahesh/code/shij/core/db/migrate/20160812081429_change_idto_uui_dforcarts.rb:4:in `change'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `exec_migration'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "using"
LINE 1: ALTER TABLE "carts" ALTER COLUMN "uuid" TYPE using uuid::uui...
                                                     ^
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:90:in `exec'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rack-mini-profiler-0.10.1/lib/patches/db/pg.rb:90:in `async_exec'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:155:in `block in execute'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:472:in `block in log'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:466:in `log'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:154:in `execute'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/schema_statements.rb:437:in `change_column'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:665:in `block in method_missing'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `block in say_with_time'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:634:in `say_with_time'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:654:in `method_missing'
/home/gvpmahesh/code/shij/core/db/migrate/20160812081429_change_idto_uui_dforcarts.rb:4:in `change'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:608:in `exec_migration'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:592:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:591:in `block in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:768:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:998:in `block in execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `block in ddl_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:1044:in `ddl_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:997:in `execute_migration_in_transaction'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:959:in `block in migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `each'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:955:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:823:in `up'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/migration.rb:801:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb:137:in `migrate'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:44:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/rake-11.2.2/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/gvpmahesh/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I have already enabled the uuid in another migration, and I don't want to drop the db So I can write id: :uuid in create table statement itself